# MeteorJS mongo collection, client and server issue

Tags: meteor

I am following academy zenva's course on meteor, but when I define  Messages = new Mongo.Collection('messages');
in the main.js file of the client, and want to insert in the browser console it doesn't work and dislays that the method is not found.

Comment: what is the full path of main.js? and can you edit your question and post the full contents of that file?

Comment: its the empty app code in the main js where I added the collection code above, but when wanting to insert in the browser console like showcased in the course it doesn't work

Comment: what is the full path of main.js? and can you edit your question and post the full contents of that file?

Answer (score 0):

try defining the collection in a file that is accessible for both server and client, i.e the `api` folder if you are using  [meteor's recommended file structure](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html)

Comment: I just want to create a collection that I can insert in the browser console and fetch data, nothing complicated but I can't seem to get it done if I only create the collection in the client main.js can you please elaborate your solution

Comment: Sure, you must define a collection on the server to actually write to  mongo, otherwise you are only writing on the client (minimongo)t. I'm not familiar at all with Zenva's meteor course, but the basics are described [here](https://guide.meteor.com/collections.html#mongo-collections). Have you read the documentation? It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing any code.